# key-value coding and to-many relationships

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, gnustep

I'm a bit confused with key value coding and to-many relationships. I've read that when having such relationship I should use [object mutableArrayValueForKey:@"key"]; to retrieve
the mutable array that holds the objects in that ordered relationship.

What I don't understand is what's the difference between mutableArrayValueForKey or just 
valueForKey.

Let me illustrate with an example (array is an NSMutableArray of self setup as a property):

```
id array1= [self valueForKey:@"array"];

NSLog(@"first element %@",[array1 objectAtIndex:1]);

id array2 = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"array"];

NSLog(@"first element %@",[array2 objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Both calls return exactly the same. In that case, what is the benefit or different of the second one?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mutableArrayValueForKey` does not return "array", it returns a proxy for "array." You can see this if you print out the classes:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.array class]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[self valueForKey:@"array"] class]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"array"] class]);
```

This prints:

```
2010-02-24 20:06:44.258 Untitled[25523:a0f] NSCFArray
2010-02-24 20:06:44.275 Untitled[25523:a0f] NSCFArray
2010-02-24 20:06:44.276 Untitled[25523:a0f] NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray
```

Read over the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/mutableArrayValueForKey:) for `mutableArrayValueForKey` for details on how that proxy works. In this particular case, you happen to have a real NSMutableArray as an ivar.  But what if there were no such ivar? You can implement KVC without an ivar backing the property, with methods like `countOf<Key>` and `objectIn<Key>AtIndex:`. There's no rule that there be an actual "array" ivar, as long as you can return sensible results to the KVC methods.

But what if you want to expose an NSMutableArray interface, but you don't have a real NSMutableArray? That's what `mutableArrayValueForKey` is for. It returns a proxy that when accessed will translate into KVC methods back to you, including sending you mutating to-many methods like `insertObject:in<Key>AtIndex:`.

This even happens in the case that you have a real ivar (as in your case), you just don't notice it because the proxy behaves so much like the real object.

Comment: Yay for explaining in detail!

Answer (score 0):

The first element is actually `objectAtIndex:0`, not `objectAtIndex:1`.

Also, the second method ensures that you can modify the returned array with `addObject:` and `removeObjectAtIndex:`, even if the value for the key `@"array"` is an immutable array.

Comment: yes I know the first element is 0. The code didn't imply it was the first. The second point makes sense, but is that the only advantage? that it returns a mutable array? Why (if the original object is an NSMutableArray) doesn't valueForKey return a mutable one?

Comment: besides, if you write your (NSMutableArray *)array; method in such a way that it returns an NSMutableArray, then the first call will actually get a mutable array, therefore it will be able to use addObject:

Comment: The code says `NSLog (@"first element %@", ...)` and then logs the *second* element.

Comment: ok well, the nslog is wrong, but there are actually a bunch of NSStrings in that array